# NextJS - multi domain sitemaps

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, seo

we are  using a next-sitemap package for generating sitemaps for my nextjs pages that are in /pages directory. For pages that comes from CMS, we are using server-sitemap.xml, with SSR.

We have like 6 differents domains, but single
project.
["en", "cs", "de", "ua", "pl" "de-AT"...]

I created function, that create use correct domain for my server-sitemap.xml so the url is always right

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  const fields: ISitemapField[] = [];

  for (const locale of i18n.locales) {
    const urls = await fetchAPI<PageEntity[]>(`/${STRAPI_ENDPOINTS.PAGES}`, { params: { locale, populate: "localizations" } });

    fields.push(
      ...urls?.map(
        ({ generatedUrl, updatedAt, localizations }) =>
          ({
            loc: `https://${languageToDomains[locale]}${generatedUrl}`,
            lastmod: updatedAt,
            alternateRefs: localizations?.map(({generatedUrl: altUrl, locale: altLocale}) => ({
              href: `https://${languageToDomains[altLocale]}${altUrl}`,
              hreflang: altLocale,
            }
            ))
          } as ISitemapField),
      ),
    );
  }

  return getServerSideSitemap(ctx, fields);
};

// Default export to prevent next.js errors
export default () => {};
```

Now i need to generate something for my routes in /pages directory, but i am totally lost and dont even know if its possible.

current code: next-sitemap.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  siteUrl: "http:localhost:3000",
  exclude: ['/server-sitemap.xml'],
  generateRobotsTxt: true,
  robotsTxtOptions: {
    additionalSitemaps: [`http:localhost:3000/server-sitemap.xml`],
  },
  transform: async (_, path) => {
    return {
      loc: path,
      lastmod: new Date().toISOString(),
    }
  }
};
```

Do you have any ideas how to do it correctly? Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to add a static route?

Comment: yes, but with multiple domains, not just locale in url. @H9ee

Answer (score 0):

ok you can use this :

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  const fields: ISitemapField[] = [];
  // add all static route here 
  const staticRoute = [ {
    loc: `https://exampleurl`,
            lastmod: updatedAt,
            alternateRefs: localizations?.map(({generatedUrl: altUrl, locale: altLocale}) => ({
              href: `https://exampleurl`,
              hreflang: altLocale,
            },
{ loc: `https://${languageToDomains[locale]}${generatedUrl}`,
            lastmod: updatedAt,
            alternateRefs: localizations?.map(({generatedUrl: altUrl, locale: altLocale}) => ({
              href: `https://${languageToDomains[altLocale]}${altUrl}`,
              hreflang: altLocale,
            }]

  for (const locale of i18n.locales) {
    const urls = await fetchAPI<PageEntity[]>(`/${STRAPI_ENDPOINTS.PAGES}`, { params: { locale, populate: "localizations" } });

    fields.push(
      ...urls?.map(
        ({ generatedUrl, updatedAt, localizations }) =>
          ({
            loc: `https://${languageToDomains[locale]}${generatedUrl}`,
            lastmod: updatedAt,
            alternateRefs: localizations?.map(({generatedUrl: altUrl, locale: altLocale}) => ({
              href: `https://${languageToDomains[altLocale]}${altUrl}`,
              hreflang: altLocale,
            }
            ))
          } as ISitemapField),
      ),
    );
  }

  const allRoute = [...staticRoute, ...fields]

  return getServerSideSitemap(ctx, allRoute);
};

// Default export to prevent next.js errors
export default () => {};
```